# How to find $ \iint_{D_R}e^{-x}\arctan(\frac{y}{x})\,dx\,dy\,$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

How to find $$ \iint_{D_R}e^{-x}\arctan\frac{y}{x}\,dx\,dy\,,$$ where $$ D_R=\left\{(x,y) \mid \frac{R}{2}\leq x\leq R, 0\leq y \leq \frac{2}{R}x-1 \right\}\,?$$

I know that
$$\int \arctan \frac{y}{x}\, dy =y \arctan \frac{y}{x} -\frac{x}{2} \ln\left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)+C$$

So how to find $$\int_{R/2}^R e^{-x} \left(\frac{2}{R}x-1 \right) \arctan \frac{\frac{2}{R}x-1}{x} -\frac{x}{2} \ln\left(1+\left(\frac{\frac{2}{R}x-1}{x}\right)^2\right)\,dx$$ and it's difficult to calculate.

Comment: It is a very hard one. When setting $R=2$ we obtain $\frac{1}{16} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}} (4-4 i) \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)+e^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}} (4+4 i) \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)+\pi +\frac{8 \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{7}\right)-\pi \right)}{e^2}-4 \left(-1+\log \left(\frac{625}{256}\right)+\tan ^{-1}(3)\right)\right)$.

Comment: And when setting $R=1$ the integral is $\frac{1}{100} \left(10 e^{-\frac{2}{5}-\frac{i}{5}} \left((2-9 i) \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{i}{5}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{i}{5}\right)\right)+e^{\frac{2 i}{5}} (2+9 i) \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{3}{5}-\frac{i}{5}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{i}{5}\right)\right)\right)+\pi  \left(-2-\frac{75}{e}\right)+10-16 \log (2)\right)$. Keeping the variable $R$ seems to explode the integral expression. Note $Ei$ is the exponential integral function.